# Client doesn't close connection to server after receiving all responses

Tags: bash, netcat

For a school project, I have to create a bash script which communicates with a distant netcat server and sends commands to this server, and gets back responses.

In my client script, I have a `sendMessage` function that sends messages to the server, and then displays the response from the server. My issue is that after receiving a response, netcat is still waiting for data from server and won't close the connection.

I already tried the -q argument, and I don't get my responses with it, the -w argument is almost what I want, but the minimum value is 1 second, which is not possible to use in my case.

Here is my function:

```
function sendMessage {
    netcat -w 1 "$ipAddress" "$port" <<< "$*"
}
```

I'm still searching on my side but I have to admit a little help would be very welcome.

Comment: How do you know that you have received the complete response from the server?

Comment: And therein lies the problem. @Zrin  Good answer below.  I'm going to use it in my own similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a working way (maybe not the best but at least it's perfectly doing what I want :D)

after all functions I send a "ENDRESPONSE" message, and on my client, I test if I have this message or not :

```
function sendMessage {
    while read line; do
        if [[ $line == "ENDRESPONSE" ]]; then
            break
        else
            echo $line
        fi
    done < <(netcat "$ipAddress" "$port" <<< "$*")
}
```

Anyway thanks for your help, I'll try to implement other solutions later !

Answer (score 1):

You can `exec` `nc` as `coproc`, send the line to the server, then use `read` with a timeout to read the response, check whether the response is complete and then close the connection by sending a signal to `nc`.

Instead of using `nc` you can perhaps also use bash TCP capabilities, like

```
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/"$HOST"/"$PORT"
read -t "$TIMEOUT" -n "$MAXLEN" line
exec 5<&- 5>&-
```