# bash ncat / nc / netcat connection won't close / stays open too long

Tags: bash, client-server, netcat

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with `bash 4.4.20`.

I'm trying to create a little daemon to schedule data transmission between threads.

On the server I am doing this:

```
ncat -l 2001 -k -c 'xargs -n1 ./atc-worker.sh'
```

On the client I am doing this:

```
echo "totally-legit-login-token" | nc 127.0.0.1 2001 -w 1
```

And it works well!

Here is the response:

```
LaunchCode=1589323120.957093305 = Now=1589323120.957093305 = URL=https://totally-legit-url.com/ = AuthToken=totally-legit-auth-token = LastID=167
```

When the server receives a request from a client, it calls my little `atc-worker.sh` script.  The server spits out a single line of text and it is back to business, serving other clients.

Thanks to the `-k` option, the server listens continuously.  Multiple clients can connect at the same time.  The only problem, is that I cannot end the connection programmatically.  I need the daemon `-k` functionality on the server to answer requests from the clients, but I need the clients to quit listening after receiving a response and get on to their other work.

Is there an EOF signal/character I can send from my `atc-worker.sh` script that would tell `nc` on the client side to disconnect?

On the client, I use the `-w 1` option to tell the client to connect for no more than a second.

But this `-w 1` option has some drawbacks.

1. **Maybe a second is too long.**  The connection should just take ~150 milliseconds and waiting out the rest of the second slows each client down even if it already has its answer.  And -as I said before- the client has chores to do!  The client shouldn't be wasting its time after it has its answer!
2. **Bad actors**  Rogue clients could connect to the server that have no intention to close out in a timely manner and I want the server to have better control and shut down bad actors.
3. **Maybe a second is too short.** `atc-worker.sh` has a mechanism to wait for a lock file to be removed if there is one.  If that lock file is there for more than a second, the connection will close before the client can receive its response.

**Possible solutions.**

1. The `atc-worker.sh` script could send a magic character set to terminate the connection.  Problem solved.
2. On the client-side set of solutions, maybe `curl` would be a suitable choice instead of `nc`?  But it would not solve my concern of being able to deal with bad actors.  Maybe these are two different problems?  Client-side closing the connection immediately after an answer is received, and server-side dealing with bad actors who will use what ever clients they choose.
3. Maybe use `expect`?  I'm investigating that now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BSD `netcat` has this option: "-N      shutdown(2) the network socket after EOF on the input.  Some servers require this to finish their work." I don't know of any equivalent for `ncat`.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  After a lot of digging, I found someone else with a similar problem.  Here is a link to his answer.

Original question:  [Client doesn't close connection to server after receiving all responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50524320/3055756)

Original Answer:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528286/3055756

Thanks @Unyxos

I modified my daemon to send an "ENDRESPONSE" line when it was done even though it does not drop the connection.  And I modified the client to look for that "ENDRESPONSE" line.  When the client gets the line, it drops the connection using the logic that @Unyxos uses below in his answer.

Here is his simple and elegant answer:

---

Finally found a working way (maybe not the best but at least it's perfectly doing what I want :D)

after all functions I send a "ENDRESPONSE" message, and on my client, I test if I have this message or not :

```
function sendMessage {
    while read line; do
        if [[ $line == "ENDRESPONSE" ]]; then
            break
        else
            echo $line
        fi
    done < <(netcat "$ipAddress" "$port" <<< "$*")
}
```

Anyway thanks for your help, I'll try to implement other solutions later !